# Supplying less than 3.3V voltage for power inputs

Tags: voltage, current, power-electronics, dc-dc-converter

I want to do a re-design for [i.MX 6Dual/6Quad](https://www.nxp.com/docs/en/data-sheet/IMX6DQCEC.pdf)  CPU-based mini-PC, where one of the DC-DC converters used to supply 3.3V for its power inputs, is going to be replaced with a new DC-DC that outputs Vout=3.22v.

My main concern is that supplying 3.22 will not be sufficient for various devices on board, including this CPU.
I did a rigorous check for all devices that are connected to the 3.3V output, and turned out that 3.3V was connected to their VCC supply pins, which in all of them, the minimum supply voltage required for operation is *lower* than 3.22V.

On the other hand, some inputs had confused me. let's give some examples:

1. VDD_HIGH_IN input in [i.MX 6Dual/6Quad](https://www.nxp.com/docs/en/data-sheet/IMX6DQCEC.pdf) : is 3.22V input is a good choice for its range? and how does -0.3V min voltage makes sense when we are talking about *VDD HIGH*?

[image]

2. VCC input for [Micro SATA Disk Chip](https://www.digikey.ch/htmldatasheets/production/1947034/0/0/1/ap-usdczzzzz49-xtm1.html) where it's VCC voltage range is 3.135V ~ 3.465V, is 3.22V input for VCC also sufficient in this case?

Since there are 3 DC-DC converters on board, and I want to replace all three of them out with a new ones out of price concerns, it turns out that in order to choose 3 similar converters, the DC-DC converter which used to supply Vout=3.3V, now will have to supply only 3.22V.

I measured the total maximal current that could be consumed from all devices that are connected to the 3.3V output (which is now 3.22V output) and the new DC-DC is able to provide such current.

Comment: Look at the "Operating ranges" tables, not the "Absolute max rating"

Comment: One thing you seem to be ignoring is the voltage drop, or distribution loss, across the board.  The output of your DC-DC converter may very well be 3.22 V, but because of I^2*R losses, the voltage at a device may be below it's required minimum.  Also note that the I^2*R loss needs to take into account both the supply path and the return (GND) path.

Comment: We usually set our power supplies to be near the high end of the operating voltage range for the devices on a board to partially compensate for distribution losses.

Comment: the lowest voltage that I can afford after the I^2*R losses is 3.135V which goes for Micro SATA Disk Chip. I need to figure out how to evaluate these losses and see if they are in the magnitude of ~ 85mv.

Comment: You also need to look at the datasheets for your dc/dc converters and determined the **minimum** possible output voltage. Is 3.22V the absolute minimum voltage or is it the nominal voltage?

Comment: No, I'm using [tps54719](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/tps54719.pdf?ts=1620478507078&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.ti.com%252Fproduct%252FTPS54719). the absolute minimum voltage is 2.95V.